# Encapsulation on WPF

Tags: wpf, encapsulation

"Code complete 2" said in a customers class, the list's interfaces should be hidden if they are not used,

but in WPF data binding in datagrid or Listbox, usually use itemssource = customers,

if customers inherits from list, then list's interfaces can not be hidden...

Are these two conflict? How to solve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Who said List's Interfaces like IEnumerable are not used  when you set  **itemssource = customers** . It is used , They are used by your ListBox ,DataGrid class to iterate through the items of your collection.

Comment: I see, could use interface ienumerable for customers.